# My code keeps throwing a matmul error when I try to compile code that uses code I have previously written for the rotation of an image

Tags: python

My code keeps throwing a matmul error and I'm stuck on how to fix it.
Here is the question:
The moon orbits the earth while the earth orbits the sun. Assuming circular
orbits, we can compute the trajectories of both the earth and the moon using only linear and
ane transformations.
Assume an orientation where both the earth and moon travel counterclockwise, with the
sun at the origin. Let pe(t) and pm(t) be the positions of the earth and the moon at time t,
respectively, and let !e and !m be each celestial body's angular velocity. For a particular time
t, we calculate pe(t) and pm(t) with the following steps.

1. Compute pe(t) by rotating the initial vector pe(0) counterclockwise about the origin by
   t!e radians.
2. Calculate the position of the moon relative to the earth at time t by rotating the vector
   pm(0)  pe(0) counterclockwise about the origin by t!m radians.
3. To compute pm(t), translate the vector resulting from the previous step by pe(t).
   Write a function that accepts a nal time T, initial positions xe and xm, and the angular
   momenta !e and !m. Assuming initial positions pe(0) = (xe; 0) and pm(0) = (xm; 0), plot
   pe(t) and pm(t) over the time interval t 2 [0; T].

Here is my code:

```
def rotate(A, theta):
    """Rotate the points in A about the origin by theta radians.

    Parameters:
        A ((2,n) ndarray): Array containing points in R2 stored as columns.
        theta (float): The rotation angle in radians.
    """
    #raise NotImplementedError("Problem 1 Incomplete")

    rotate_transform = np.array([[np.cos(theta), -1*np.sin(theta)], [np.sin(theta), np.cos(theta)]])
    return rotate_transform @ A

def solar_system(T, x_e, x_m, omega_e, omega_m):
    """Plot the trajectories of the earth and moon over the time interval [0,T]
    assuming the initial position of the earth is (x_e,0) and the initial
    position of the moon is (x_m,0).

    Parameters:
        T (int): The final time.
        x_e (float): The earth's initial x coordinate.
        x_m (float): The moon's initial x coordinate.
        omega_e (float): The earth's angular velocity.
        omega_m (float): The moon's angular velocity.
    """
    #raise NotImplementedError("Problem 2 Incomplete")
    
    t = np.linspace(0, T, 100)
    earth_pos = [[x_e, 0]]
    moom_pos = [[x_m, 0]]
    for i in t:
        new_pos_e = rotate(x_e, t*omega_e)
        earth_pos.append(new_pos_e)
        temp_pos_m = rotate((x_m - x_e), t*omega_m)
        new_pos_m = np.dot(temp_pos_m, new_pos_e)
        moon_pos.append(new_pos_m)
        
    earth_pos1 = np.array(earth_pos)
    moon_pos1 = np.array(moon_pos)
        
    plt.plot(earth_pos1[:,0], earth_pos1[:,1], 'b-', label="Earth")
    plt.plot(moon_pos1[:,0], moon_pos1[:,1], 'o-', label="Moon")
    plt.title("Earth and Moon Rotation")
    plt.show()
    plt.legend()
        
solar_system((3*np.pi)/2, 10, 11, 1, 13)
```

And this is the error I keep receiving:

> ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 does not have enough dimensions
> (has 0, gufunc core with signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) requires 1)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: to where does the error point to?

Comment: @sai it points to my ```return rotate_transform @ A ``` but I not sure why because that function looks correct to me

Comment: check the shapes of `rotate_transform and A` before you multiply them `rotate_transform @ A`